# Error al eliminar filas del JTable

Tags: java, jtable

Tengo un `JTable` donde quiero **eliminar filas seleccionadas** pero no funciona de la forma correcta.

Selecciono una fila, pulso **Eliminar** y aparece **eliminada** de la tabla. **Cierro el programa** lo vuelvo a abrir y me aparecen los mismos registros que inicialmente. **Y si selecciono varias filas, no elimina.**

**Código:**

```
public class Listado_clientes extends javax.swing.JFrame{
    public Listado_clientes() {
        initComponents();

        //Contador de clientes.
        label_contador.setText("Hay "+Conexiones.contar_clientes()+" clientes registrados.");

        try {
            DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
            tabla_clientes.setModel(modelo);

            //Realizamos la consulta.
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            Connection con = Conexiones.conexion_a_BBDD("agenda");

            String sql = "SELECT dni, nombre, apellidos, telefono, direccion, ciudad, email FROM clientes";
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            ResultSetMetaData rsMd = (ResultSetMetaData) rs.getMetaData();
            int cantidadColumnas = rsMd.getColumnCount();

            modelo.addColumn("DNI");
            modelo.addColumn("NOMBRE");
            modelo.addColumn("APELLIDOS");
            modelo.addColumn("TELEFONO");
            modelo.addColumn("DIRECCION");
            modelo.addColumn("CIUDAD");
            modelo.addColumn("EMAIL");

            //Crear las columnas de la tabla, con el ancho X.
            tabla_clientes.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(90); //aquí el DNI
            tabla_clientes.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(110);
            tabla_clientes.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(160);
            tabla_clientes.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(80);
            tabla_clientes.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(140);
            tabla_clientes.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(100);
            tabla_clientes.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setPreferredWidth(150);

            //Recorrer el array e imprimir los datos en las celdas.
            while (rs.next()) {
                Object[] filas = new Object[cantidadColumnas];
                for (int i=0; i<cantidadColumnas; i++) {
                    filas[i] = rs.getObject(i+1);
                }
                modelo.addRow(filas);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.toString());
        }
    }


    private void button_eliminarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
        DefaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel) tabla_clientes.getModel();

        int fila = tabla_clientes.getSelectedRow();
        int confirmado = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "¿Deseas eliminar los clientes?", "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        if (JOptionPane.OK_OPTION == confirmado){
            if (fila >= 0) {
               int[] filasselec  = tabla_clientes.getSelectedRows();

                for (int i=0; i<filasselec.length; i++){
                    modelo.removeRow(filasselec[i]);
                    String dni_a_eliminar = (String) tabla_clientes.getValueAt(i, 0);
                    Conexiones.eliminar_cliente(dni_a_eliminar);
                }
               label_contador.setText("Hay "+Conexiones.contar_clientes()+" clientes registrados.");
            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debe seleccionar al menos un cliente.");
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

**eliminar_cliente():**

```
public static void eliminar_cliente(String DNI){
        String bbdd = Conexiones.bbdd;
        Connection c = (Connection) Conexiones.conexion_a_BBDD(bbdd);
        Statement stm;
        ResultSet rs;
        try{
            //Preparamos la consulta a realizar...
            stm = c.createStatement();
            //Consulta para eliminar un cliente en la base de datos.
            String eliminar_clientes = "DELETE FROM clientes WHERE dni = '"+DNI+"';";
            int resultado1 = 1;
            //System.out.println(eliminar_clientes);
            resultado1 = stm.executeUpdate(eliminar_clientes);
            if(resultado1<=0){
                throw new SQLException();
            }else{
                //System.out.println("Cliente eliminado de la tabla clientes.");
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Borrado realizado con éxito.");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                c.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Conexiones.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Ejemplo visual de la app:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pon a funcionar las líneas comentadas//System.out.println(eliminar_clientes);
//System.out.println("Cliente eliminado de la tabla clientes.");
Y así sabrás si se forma bien la sentencia DELETE y si luego se ejecuta correctamente. Y nos comentas los resultados

Comment: Si se forma bien la DELETE, por eso los tengo puestos, y comentados.

Answer (score 1):

Si los registros son borrados correctamente, la única opción para que luego salgan de nuevo es que se haya generado un rollback en la base de datos. Para evitar esto, prueba a ejecutar un COMMIT antes de cerrar la conexión.

Un tip extra: A partir de la versión 1.7, java introdujo los try-with-resources para conexiones a distintas partes, como bufferes de archivos, sockets, conexiones sql... y así evitar tener que escribir el dichoso .close en todas ellas.

El formato es:

```
try(declaración conexion){
  codigo
} catch...
```

Aplicado a tu código sería:

```
try(Connection c = (Connection) Conexiones.conexion_a_BBDD(bbdd);){
  codigo
} catch...
```

(y sin finally, ya que el objeto conexion se cierra al acabar el try)
Si se tienen varias conexiones como una conexion a base de datos, un buffer, y un socket todo dentro de un mismo try... se declaran los 3 dentro del paréntesis, separados por puntos y comas ";"

Comment: En mi caso no creo que sea problema de rollback commit, sino un error de sintáxis.

Comment: ¿Cómo quedaría en mi programa?

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente, logré solucionarlo de la siguiente manera.

Tenía:

```
for (int i=0; i<rowsselec.length; i++){
    modelo.removeRow(rowsselec[i]);
    String dni_delete = (String) tabla_clientes.getValueAt(i, 0);
    Conexiones.eliminar_cliente(dni_delete);
}
```

**Y lo solucioné con:**

```
for (int i=0; i<rowsselec.length; i++){
    String dni_delete = (String) tabla_clientes.getValueAt(i, 0);
    Conexiones.eliminar_cliente(dni_delete);
    modelo.removeRow(rowsselec[i]);
}
```

Yo tenía que: conseguir la fila -id-, borrarlo de la base de datos y, finalmente, de la tabla.

Esto significa que si algo sale mal, lo sabré, porque la fila no se ha eliminado de la tabla.